# Magento 2 Class CoinGate\Merchant does not exist

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, payment-methods, di, class-not-found

I have installed the **CoinGage_Merchant** module in **Magento 2.3** setup but when I fire **di:compile command** it is showing below error.
I set the **generated folder permission 777 before compile command** but still, it is giving an error.

> Class CoinGate\Merchant does not exist
>     Class CoinGate\Merchant\Model\Payment\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly, because the 'generated'
>      directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/magento setup:di:compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the requested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.

Does anyone has any idea, please share.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run below commands to fix this issue

```
composer require coingate/coingate-php
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your help but will it affect any other folder or file?

Comment: No this will not affect any other files but it will download require lib for your extension.

Comment: Showing error as below:

A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Comment: What is your PHP and Magento version ? Can you please let me know that ?

Comment: PHP 7.1.33 and Magento 2.3.3

Comment: I run same command and that is working

Comment: can you please check your composer version?

Comment: **composer -v** use this command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101260/discussion-between-utsav-gupta-and-kishan-savaliya).